# AWS loadbalancer logs from s3 to elastic search

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

I have enabled my ELB logs to S3 bucket. I am trying to send S3 logs to Elasticsearch using below script in lambda.

Logs are stored in s3 bucket as *.log.gz format.How to send send zip file to elasticsearch in json format.

I tried referring
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-aws-integrations.html#es-aws-integrations-s3-lambda-es with no luck.

Let me know if there is better approach to do this.

```
import boto3
import re
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

region = '' # e.g. us-west-1
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

host = '' # the Amazon ES domain, including https://
index = 'lambda-s3-index'
type = 'lambda-type'
url = host + '/' + index + '/' + type

headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }  
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Regular expressions used to parse some simple log lines
ip_pattern = re.compile('(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)')
time_pattern = re.compile('\[(\d+\/\w\w\w\/\d\d\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s-\d\d\d\d)\]')

message_pattern = re.compile('\"(.+)\"')

# Lambda execution starts here
def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:

        # Get the bucket name and key for the new file
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']

        # Get, read, and split the file into lines
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        body = obj['Body'].read()
        lines = body.splitlines()

        # Match the regular expressions to each line and index the JSON
        for line in lines:
            ip = ip_pattern.search(line).group(1)
            timestamp = time_pattern.search(line).group(1)
            message = message_pattern.search(line).group(1)

            document = { "ip": ip, "timestamp": timestamp, "message": message }
            r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=document, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Did you try to fake one JSON Event and Run Lambda via manually?

Comment: The link you are referring is talking about files which are not compressed. But your question is more around *.gz compressed files. Your code is missing lines to decompress S3 file first. Ex: `striodata = StringIO.StringIO(body) with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=striodata, mode='r') as f:
            lines = (f.read()).splitlines()`
. Let me know if this is the issue then I will paste it as answer with little bit more code.

Answer (score 1):

The better approach to do this is to use Logstash with s3 input plugin installed for parsing ELB access logs and send it to elastic search.

logstash.conf:

```
input { 
  s3 {
    access_key_id => "..."
    secret_access_key => "..."
    bucket => "..."
    region => "eu-central-1"
    prefix => "dxlb/AWSLogs/.../elasticloadbalancing/eu-central-1/2019/09/"
    type   => "elb"
  }
}

filter {
   if [type] == "elb" {
    grok {
         match => [ "message", "%{WORD:connection} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:elb} %{IP:clientip}:%{INT:clientport:float} (?:(%{IP:backendip}:?:%{INT:backendport:int})|-) %{NUMBER:request_processing_time:float} %{NUMBER:backend_processing_time:float} %{N
UMBER:response_processing_time:float} (?:-|%{INT:elb_status_code:int}) (?:-|%{INT:backend_status_code:int}) %{INT:received_bytes:int} %{INT:sent_bytes:int} \"%{ELB_REQUEST_LINE}\" \"(?:-|%{DATA:user_agent})\" (?:-|%{NOTSPACE:ssl_cipher}) (?:-|%{NOTSPACE:ssl_protocol})
" ]
        #match => ["message", "%{ELB_ACCESS_LOG} \"%{DATA:userAgent}\"( %{NOTSPACE:ssl_cipher} %{NOTSPACE:ssl_protocol})?"]
   }
   date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
    }
     geoip {
      source => "clientip"
    }
  }
}

output {
if [type] == "elb" {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["http://node:9200"]
                index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM}" 
                user => "..."
                password => "..."
        }
}
}
```